# `docker-credential-gcloud` not in system PATH

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

After the latest updates to gcloud and docker I'm unable to access images on my google container repository.  Locally when I run: `gcloud auth configure-docker` as per the instructions after updating gcloud, I get the following message:

```
WARNING: `docker-credential-gcloud` not in system PATH.
gcloud's Docker credential helper can be configured but it will not work until this is corrected.
gcloud credential helpers already registered correctly.
```

Running `which docker-credential-gcloud` returns `docker-credential-gcloud not found`.

I have no other gcloud-related path issues and for the life of me can't figure out how to install/add docker-credential-gcloud to path. Here's what I have installed (shown via `gcloud version`):

```
Google Cloud SDK 197.0.0
beta 2017.09.15
bq 2.0.31
container-builder-local
core 2018.04.06
docker-credential-gcr
gsutil 4.30
```

I also have Docker CE Version 18.03.0-ce-mac60 (23751).

Here's my $PATH:`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

I also ran `source /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc` on original gcloud install.

Comment: How did you install `gcloud`? `docker-credential-gcloud` should normally be co-located with `gcloud` itself within the same folder on your path.

Comment: Also, if you have already have `docker-credential-gcr`, you can continue using it instead, presuming `docker-credential-gcr configure-docker` works without incident...

Comment: Looks like my only missing step was to have completely closed the terminal and restarted...stupid mistake. Thanks for looking into this :)

Comment: I actually installed `docker-credential-gcr` because `docker-credential-gcloud` wasn't co-located with gcloud. Still interested in an answer to how to fix that...

Comment: What method did you use to install `gcloud`? How did you download it?

Comment: `brew cask install --appdir="/Applications" google-cloud-sdk`

Comment: Seems like the Homebrew installation method doesn't include some of the standard utilities that are included with other installations. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know which utilities/have a link you can share? What install method do you recommend?

Comment: I did a fresh install via the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos and I'm back to square one. Credentials store error: StoreError('docker-credential-gcr not installed or not available in PATH'

Comment: Here's our getting started doc: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/quickstart

Comment: Does `gcloud auth configure-docker` work now for you? Did you use the install script? What's the output of `which gcloud`?

Comment: Do you use `docker` with `sudo`? In that case, you need to also run `configure-docker` as sudo.

Comment: Ended up figuring it out the missing step with https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1396 . Still requires docker-credential-gcr though. Yes to `gcloud auth configure-docker` and `which gcloud` correctly points to where I manually put the folder (in home). I use docker w/o sudo.

Comment: Excellent, glad you found the root cause. I'm guessing that `docker-credential-gcr` was giving you errors because the gcloud SDK's bin directory got wiped out during your re-install.

Comment: Just delete `.docker/config.json` https://superuser.com/a/1411019/1238179

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the `source...` statement. That had somehow gotten commented-out of my .zshrc.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

**Notice**: All `docker-credential-gcr` below can be replaced with `docker-credential-gcloud`. I think it is just different versions of gcloud, I might be wrong.

I used Homebrew Cask to install gcloud too. I installed `docker-credential-gcr` with

```
$ gcloud components install docker-credential-gcr
```

And then like you said, `which docker-credential-gcr` doesn't gave you anything.

So I ran `which gcloud` to find there is a symlink to gcloud in `/usr/local/bin`. This symlink is created by Homebrew when you installed gcloud at first place. Now `docker-credential-gcr` wasn't installed by Homebrew but by gcloud itself, so there isn't a symlink.

I called `readlink /usr/local/bin/gcloud` and found out gcloud is installed in `/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin/`.

Then:

```
$ ls /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin
```

There you should see `docker-credential-gcr` listed there.

I simply linked it to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
$ ln -s \
    /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin/docker-credential-gcr \
    /usr/local/bin/
```

Then run:

```
$ docker-credential-gcr configure-docker
```

It should succeed.

Comment: This answer almost worked for me, but needed a tweak. The symlink step seemed to have an outdated/typo in it. It referenced `docker-credential-gcr` instead of `docker-credential-gcloud`. Updating that step as below worked for me.


`$ ln -s /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin/docker-credential-gcloud /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: Thank you Jumand for noticing it. It was pure type. I am having it corrected.

Comment: I just checked. On my machine it is docker-credential-gcr. And I ran `gcloud components list` docker-credential-gcloud isn't there. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: @jumand - I think that `docker-credential-gcr` is the new tool, and `-gcloud` is the deprecated one. See https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

Comment: for me it was not in `/usr/local/Caskroom/` but in `/snap/` (using ubuntu)

Answer (score 33):

Just had the same issue on Windows, running Docker with Linux containers, Docker engine v19.03.8. Using docker compose. I do not use gcloud for my dockerfiles...

> DT1001    dockerpycreds.errors.InitializationError:
>   docker-credential-gcloud not installed or not available in PATH

1. Option 1: Edit the docker configuration file and remove all `gcloud` entries from there.

   - Windows `c:/Users/<your account>/.docker/config.json`
   - Linux & MacOS `~/.docker/config.json`
2. Option 2: Go to Troubleshoot -> Reset to factory defaults.

After this my docker compose was creating containers and running the images without any issues.

Comment: I had to make credHelpers empty `"credHelpers":{}`. thanks worked for me.

Comment: I also cleared `"credHelpers":{}` as mentioned by @amir-chatrbahr, but it was filled again. I assume it can come from updating Docker Desktop or IntelliJ (where I have an unconfigured GCloud plugin)?

Comment: I was having the same problem trying to `docker-compose build` locally, after uninstalling gcloud, so after removing both files it worked fine: `/usr/bin/docker-credential-gcloud` and `~/.docker/config.json`

Comment: Helped just to remove `~/.docker/config.json` and restart Docker.

Answer (score 7):

### On MacOS

#### Step 1：

Install gcloud and docker-credential-gcr,
following this  [tutorial](https://pvital.wordpress.com/2020/09/08/fixing-docker-credential-gcloud-not-installed-or-not-available-in-path-macos-version/)

#### Step 2:

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/bin/docker-credential-gcr /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-gcloud
```

#### Step 3:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.docker
```

#### Step 4:

```
$ docker-compose build --pull
```

Finished!

Answer (score 4):

Never found a way to directly resolve the `docker-credential-gcloud` issue, but the following got me up and running again. WARNING: the following will delete all your existing docker images and install a bunch of gcloud utilities:

1. `gcloud components install docker-credential-gcr`,
2. Restart the terminal completely
3. `docker-credential-gcr configure-docker`.
4. `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty`
5. `umount /var/lib/docker/overlay2`
6. `rm -rf /var/lib/docker`
7. Restart the terminal completely.

Comment: On executing statement 3 we received this warning. Any concern?  "...WARNING: Unable to execute `docker version`: exit status 1
This is expected if `docker` is not installed, or if `dockerd` cannot be reached..."

Comment: I don't remember encountering that, but the accepted answer makes a lot more sense than this one I think

Answer (score 3):

The new version of google-cloud-sdk has only `docker-credential-gcr` but not `docker-credential-gcloud` anymore. On the other hand one of my python packages always requested `docker-credential-gcloud`.

The solution was to symlink `docker-credential-gcloud` to `docker-credential-gcr`:

```
ln -s /path/to/google-cloud-sdk/bin/docker-credential-gcr /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-gcloud
```

`ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep docker` should now print:

```
...
docker-credential-gcloud -> /path/to/google-cloud-sdk/bin/docker-credential-gcr
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, this error indicates that your `$PATH` variable has been clobbered by a package or program you have recently installed so that the Google Cloud SDK can't be found.

`$PATH` is altered by many programs when they install by altering `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` or their non-bash equivalents. With a bad `$PATH`, Google Cloud SDK is configured in `docker` but can't be seen as executables so we get this error. This assumes you have used the Google Cloud SDK in the past, but if `gcloud` is configured with your docker then you probably have. Don't reinstall gcloud or disable it, you already have it on your system and that is fine.

*The solution then is to fix your* `$PATH`, *not to install anything.*

```sh
echo $PATH
```

This should be a pretty long `:` delimited list of directories that your files are in. Do you see a `google-cloud-sdk/bin` in the string? Is the string way too short given all the trouble you've gotten into in your life on this computer? You use NVM but it is missing? Use Homebrew but it is missing? Try `brew` from the command line, does it work?

If the answer is "no" to any of the above, inspect the files above to see if there are any new entries at the bottom of each that might have broken things. Did you just install anything new?

Something is clobbering your `$PATH` and you need to figure out what that is. For me it is usually something to do with Anaconda Python via the `conda init` command. For you it might be `nvm` or something else. Figure out what it is and fix the problem. Don't start over with a new `$PATH` and install the same stuff over again or disable `gcloud` authentication.

Answer (score 1):

It really seems to be something with the Homebrew Cask. I uninstalled the cask and then reinstalled the Google Cloud SDK by manually [downloading the tar ball](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos) and running the packaged install script as described there.

Now `docker-credential-gcloud` is in my path:

```
$ which docker-credential-gcloud
/Users/moritz/google-cloud-sdk/bin/docker-credential-gcloud
```

Comment: This worked for me. For the love of god I couldn't find the executable and was about to clone and run the repo. 

After extracting ran: `./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init` then  `./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud components install docker-credential-gcr` then just add the bin to your `$PATH`

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out what Google is trying to achieve here. On Linux there is docker-credential-gcloud and on Windows there is docker-credential-gcr.exe, and then there is docker-credential-gcloud.cmd which calls gcloud auth docker-helper. This is kind of a nightmare if you're trying to write portable build scripts or gradle rules because not everything seems capable of finding and calling docker-credential-gcloud.cmd when you exec docker-credential-gcloud... it might work from the dos prompt, but in general doesn't work.

After a ton of fooling around with .bat scripts, cygwin scripts, .cmd scripts and so forth, I found the best solution was to go into the gcloud installation and just copy docker-credential-gcr.exe docker-credential-gcloud.exe ... not a very satisfying solution, but is the only thing I found that would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue when I tried to SSH from Google Cloud Build into an Engine VM Instance, so I had

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['compute', 'ssh',
         '--project', '$PROJECT_ID',
         '--zone', 'asia-southeast1-b',
         '--strict-host-key-checking=no',
         'username@instance-1',
         '--command' ,'sh start.sh'
```

My `start.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Started: $(date --iso-8601=seconds)"

docker pull gcr.io/aaa/bbbc/cccc

echo "Finished: $(date --iso-8601=seconds)"
```

The issue was `How to set PATH when running a ssh command?`

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332532/how-to-set-path-when-running-a-ssh-command

Answer (score 0):

So I just faced the same problem where I am trying to pull an image from GCR to an GCP instance and want to share my solution.

I ran `gcloud auth configure-docker` and got the warning:

```
WARNING: `docker-credential-gcloud\` not in system PATH.
gcloud's Docker credential helper can be configured but it will not work until this is corrected.
```

I applied the accepted answer for this thread and ran `gcloud components install docker-credential-gcr` and got a long error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.components.install) You cannot perform this action because this Cloud SDK installation is managed by an external package manager.
Please consider using a separate installation of the Cloud SDK created through the default mechanism described at: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
```

When no solution was working, I uninstalled the Google provided `google-cloud-sdk` package that was installed via `snap` and instlled with distro specifice package manager, for me that is `apt-get` as instructed in the [Installing Google Cloud SDK: Installation options](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install#installation_options) page and re-ran the `gcloud auth configure-docker` and this time it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was due to how **WSL 1** works with Docker on **Windows**. At first I only installed and initialized `gcloud` in WSL Ubuntu, not in Windows. However as Docker daemon is actually run by Windows, you need to install `gcloud` for Windows as well (and don't forget to run all of the inits and authorizations there).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10/11, you need to ensure that `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\` is **added to your system `$PATH` environment variable**. It may not have been added if the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) was not able to add it during GCloud installation. So add it manually like this:

1. Windows Task Bar ➔ Press the search icon  or the search bar
2. Type `"environment"` ➔ and click on `"Edit the System Environment Variables"` (ensure that you have Administrator access)
3. At the bottom of the dialog, click the <kbd>Environment Variables...</kbd> button
4. `System Variables` ➔ click `Path` ➔ <kbd>Edit...</kbd> ➔ <kbd>New</kbd> ➔ paste in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\` (replace "USERNAME" with your username)
5. Close and restart any open Command Prompt windows.

Then verify on the [Git Bash for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) console:

1. Optional: Note that the `AppData` folder is hidden by default, so you may want to [unhide AppData](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/appdata-where-to-find-the-appdata-folder-in-windows-10/) first, to see its contents.
2. Restart the Git Bash Terminal window
3. `echo $PATH` ➔ This should print a long string that contains: `:/c/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin`
4. `where docker-credential-gcloud` ➔ This should print `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\docker-credential-gcloud.cmd`