# is it possible to use podman in macbook pro with M1 pro chip

Tags: macos, podman

I want to use podman in macbook pro with M1 pro chip. First I run this command to initial podman:

```
➜  retire git:(master) podman machine init
Downloading VM image: fedora-coreos-36.20220511.dev.0-qemu.aarch64.qcow2.xz: done
Extracting compressed file
Image resized.
Machine init complete
To start your machine run:

    podman machine start
```

After start the VM, then using this command to pull but encount an error:

```
➜  retire git:(master) podman pull registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/yapi:0ac4a62af8f232cae90ac955708c23d8386b2033
Error: 1 error occurred:
    * error getting credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-gcloud": executable file not found in $PATH, out: ``
```

is it possible to use podman in macOS? what should I do to fixed this problem?

Comment: pull which images? it looks like u have other plugins enabled, try below command to make sure to download from docker.io `podman pull docker.io/hello-world`

Answer (score 2):

Podman has been supported on M1 chips since October: https://podman.io/blogs/2021/10/04/m1macs.html

The error you're getting spells it out for you - `"docker-credential-gloud": executable file not found in $PATH`

This indicates that you either don't have `gcloud` and `docker-credential-gcloud` installed, or there is a problem with your current install.

Try re-installing the Google components if you haven't already.

Also: see existing [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49780218/docker-credential-gcloud-not-in-system-path)

Comment: But I did not using gcloud still need to install the components? @Joel